# Debian+Remove Files That Start With *

Tags: cron, debian

I have setup a cronjob to remove a file that is being generated by another script each hour.

The file´s name: `inc.php?cronUsers`

My current command looks like this:

```
rm -f "/root/inc.php?cronUsers"
```

The problem is that, when there are more than one file, the file names change like this:

`inc.php?cronUsers.1`,`inc.php?cronUsers.2` and so on..

I am realy new to all of this, so the only lucky guess was to do:

```
rm -f "/root/inc.php?cronUsers.*"
```

But this seems not work.

How else could I delete all files that start with `inc.php?cronUsers` ?

Comment: Why would any1 vote to close this question?? Could you please explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rm -f inc.php\?cronUsers*

seems to work :

```
$ touch "inc.php?cronUsers.1"
$ touch "inc.php?cronUsers.2"
$ touch "inc.php?cronUsers"
$ ls
inc.php?cronUsers  inc.php?cronUsers.1  inc.php?cronUsers.2
$ rm -f inc.php\?cronUsers*
$ ls
<empty> :)
```

Regards

*(why did you write your question title as "that starts with *" ?? Did I miss something?)*

Comment: Works :) I kinda wonder why this works and `rm -f "/root/inc.php?cronUsers.*"` doesnt, but it doesnt really matter now :) About the title: No.. I just wanted to somehow express that the files I am trying to delete have different names...I think I did not really succeed at doing so :/